# Apache Camel consumer.delay MAX value

Tags: apache-camel

What is the maximum value that we can set for apache camel consumer.delay ?
For example i need to set it to 3 Months. is this possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its using the scheduled executor service from the Java JVM, so you can use any value it supports. And yes a value for 3 months is possible. But whether that is a good idea is another story.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The reason i have to use consumer.delay is because i use it in the sftp uri parameter. Im using camel 2.9.2 with Spring 2.6. Can you suggest a way for me to schedule it in the sftp uri without having to upgrade the camel or spring. the following is my sftp uri 
sftp://test@testserver//TEMP?password=test&consumer.delay=2m&disconnect=true&exclude=.*_ACK.zip&move=$simple{file:name.noext}_ACK.$simple{file:name.ext}&knownHostsFile=/fingerprints/test/known_hosts